# Create Custom Dagger 2 Scope with Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm trying to convert a Java code into Kotlin for custom dagger scope creation.

Here is Java code:

```
@Documented
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomScope {
}
```

Once converted into kotlin here is the result

```
@Scope
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) annotation class CustomScope
```

I have a type mismatch with `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`.I have the following error message :Required Type is AnnotationRetention but RetentionPolicy type was found.

Also @interface seems to have been replaced.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `Retention` annotation class which you might have used is from the Kotlin's library (from the package `kotlin.annotation`).

It expects a property of the enum type `AnnotationRetention`. So, you can do something like this:

```
@MustBeDocumented
@Scope
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class CustomScope
```

Btw, if you look at the `Annotations.kt` file, you will see that that the `Retention` annotation will take the default property `AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME` when you don't pass anything to it.

So, just `@Retention` annotation will do too.

Comment: also note that the annotation should be in that order: MustBeDocumented, Scope & Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME) other than that order the scoping won't work